# Why I cannot import module by IDLE (Python 3.8 64-bit)

Tags: python, module

I have began to learn python.It looks like smooth until I encounter the module section. Firstly, I get a basic piece like this:

```
def greeting(name):
  print("Hello, " + name)
```

Then I saved it under the file name mymodule.py. When I import these codes, it made error:

```
import mymodule
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import mymodule
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\mymodule.py", line 1
    Python 3.8.1 (tags/v3.8.1:1b293b6, Dec 18 2019, 23:11:46) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Thanks for your support!

Comment: Try ``from mymodule import greetings``

Comment: `...mymodule.py", line 1 ... SyntaxError: invalid syntax"` This is why, your code has a syntax error on line 1 and so the module file cannot be imported. If you include your full code properly formatted, then it will be possible to point out where the syntax error is.

Comment: 1. Your path look weird. Did you actually store the file there? 2. Can you check the content of the file given with something that is not IDLE?

Comment: It looks like you copied an interpreter session transcript into `mymodule.py` or something like that. There shouldn't be a bunch of interpreter build information at the top of your module.

Comment: I tried another IDE( Thonny) and it worked.
Thanks you guys!